# Singing PM: 'Fats' Putin over the top of 'Blueberry Hill' with piano solo

Tags: comprehension

Example [(YouTube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV4IjHz2yIo):

> Singing PM: 'Fats' Putin over the top of 'Blueberry Hill' with piano solo

I don't understand what part of speech the word 'Fats' is used as. As an adjective that describes Putin? Also, how do you understand the phrasing *over the top of 'Blueberry Hill'*?

Comment: Who sang Blueberry Hill, originally? 'Fats' Domino.

Comment: This is frightening.

Comment: Clearly, 'Fats' is an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the song was originally by singer "Fats" Domino, and so '"Fats" Putin' is a reference to this.

Which, to answer the question, makes "Fats" a **nickname** (or as a part of speech, a **proper noun**).

And because I've just realised I missed the second half of your question...

To sing "over the top of" something usually means a karaoke-style situation: there's a performance (more often recorded, but in this video live), and you're singing it too... but your voice is being heard "over the top of" it, because you've got a microphone or just a loud voice.

Now, normally you wouldn't say that (for instance) the lead singer of a band is singing "over the top of" the backup singers and the musicians; they're *part of* the performance. But in this video, it's an appropriate description, because Putin isn't really part of the band. He's there because it's a charity event where famous people do unusual things like this. So it's fair to say the band is performing so that Putin has something to sing "over the top of".

Answer (score 0):

Because he performed the 'Fats Domino's rock n' roll version of the Blueberry Hill song.

[This is Fats Domino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fats_Domino)